# How to install Imagick xampp windows 10

Tags: xampp, imagemagick, imagick

I installed ImageMagick-7.0.7-27-Q16-x86-dll then copied php_imagick.dll to php/ext folder and also wrote extension=php_imagick.dll in php.ini. there are no error in xampp but when i try to use Imagick class

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Imagick' not found

i saw previous questions like this but there is no answer

`$img = new Imagick($path);
    $img->cropThumbnailImage(1080, 600);
    $img->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
    $img->writeImage('public/images/main-slider/'.$id.'.jpg');`